# I can't figure out why the scoring isn't working in my rock, paper, scissors game

Tags: javascript

The game works fine except that the scores won't increment and my "referee" box isn't displaying the text I have assigned it based on the outcome.

I used an if else statement to randomly assign the computers choice and replace the image and set the computerChoice variable accordingly. I used and if elsee statement for the user input to assign the correct image and set the userChoice variable. I then used a separate nested set of if else statements to compare the computerCoice and userChoice Variable and output text in the referee box as well as ad 1 point to the winners score box but this part isn't working. Any Ideas?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</title>
    <style>
        .clear {clear: both;}
        .box {width: 160px; height: 150px; float: left; border: 4px solid #000;}
        .wrap {width: 110px; float: left;}
        .wrap input {width: 85px;}
        form {width: 340px; margin: 20px auto 0 auto;}
    </style>

    <script>
    var referee = document.getElementById('ref').value;
    var userScore = document.getElementById('userScore').value;
    var computerScore = document.getElementById('compScore').value;
        userScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;

        function startGame() {

            var computerChoice = Math.random();

                if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= .33) {
                    computerChoice = "rock"
                    document.getElementById("compPic").src = "rock.jpg";

                } else if (computerChoice >= .34 && computerChoice <= .66) {
                    computerChoice = "paper"
                    document.getElementById("compPic").src = "paper.jpg";

                }else if (computerChoice >= .67 && computerChoice <= 1){
                    computerChoice = "scissors"
                    document.getElementById("compPic").src = "scissors.jpg";
                };

            var userChoice = document.getElementById('userChoice').value;

                if (userChoice === "rock" || userChoice === "Rock") {
                    userChoice = "rock";
                    document.getElementById("userPic").src = "rock.jpg";

                } else if (userChoice === "paper" || userChoice === "Paper") {
                    userChoice = "paper";
                    document.getElementById("userPic").src = "paper.jpg";

                } else if (userChoice === "scissors" || userChoice === "Scissors") {
                    userChoice = "scissors";
                    document.getElementById("userPic").src = "scissors.jpg";
                };



                if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
                    referee = "Tie!";
                }else if (userChoice === 'rock') {
                    if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
                        referee = 'Computer Wins!';
                        computerScore = ++computerScore;    
                    } else if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
                        referee = 'You Wins!';
                        userScore = ++userScore;
                    };
                }else if (userChoice === 'paper') {
                    if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
                        referee = 'Computer Wins!';
                        computerScore = ++computerScore;    
                    } else if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
                        referee = 'You Wins!';
                        userScore = ++userScore;
                    };
                }else if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
                    if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
                        referee = 'Computer Wins!';
                        computerScore = ++computerScore;    
                    } else if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
                        referee = 'You Wins!';
                        userScore = ++userScore;
                    };
                };

        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>

        <div class="box"><img id="userPic" src="rps.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box"><img id="compPic" src="rps.jpg"></div>
        <br class="clear"><br>

        <div class="wrap">
            <label for="userScore">User Score:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="userScore" id="userScore" value="" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <label for="ref">Referee:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="ref" id="ref" placeholder="Referee's Call..." value="" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <label for="compScore">Computer Score:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="compScore" id="compScore" value="" readonly>
        </div>

        <br class="clear"><br>

        <label for="userChoice">Choose Your Weapon:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="userChoice" id="userChoice" placeholder="Rock, Paper, or Scissors?">
        <input type="button" value="Battle!" onclick="startGame()">

    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (OT) One has to type every time the whole word? Why don't you create buttons [Rock] [Paper] [Scissors] so the player can just click!

Comment: J-Dizzle can you elaborate? I replace my == with === and the scoring and referee functions still don't work.

Comment: Roko, I would and did but my teacher wants it his way so I have to do it like this.

Comment: In your code: you first GET a value using `var userScore = docum...` and than afterwards you reset it to `0` like `userScore = 0;`. It'll always result 0!

Comment: Roko, that make sense however `userScore = 0;` does not change the value of the input field to 0 either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must right user score to user score input field. Second you score will be reset on every game.. its not commutative.. I don't you want this or its missed by you for commutative.. define  userScore = 0; computerScore = 0; before function definition.

Try This

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</title>
    <style>
        .clear {clear: both;}
        .box {width: 160px; height: 150px; float: left; border: 4px solid #000;}
        .wrap {width: 110px; float: left;}
        .wrap input {width: 85px;}
        form {width: 340px; margin: 20px auto 0 auto;}
    </style>

    <script>
    //var referee = document.getElementById('ref').value;
    //var userScore = document.getElementById('userScore').value;
    //var computerScore = document.getElementById('compScore').value;
        userScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;

        function startGame() {

            var computerChoice = Math.random();

                if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= .33) {
                    computerChoice = "rock"
                    //document.getElementById("compPic").src = "rock.jpg";

                } else if (computerChoice >= .34 && computerChoice <= .66) {
                    computerChoice = "paper"
                    //document.getElementById("compPic").src = "paper.jpg";

                }else if (computerChoice >= .67 && computerChoice <= 1){
                    computerChoice = "scissors"
                    //document.getElementById("compPic").src = "scissors.jpg";
                };

            var userChoice = document.getElementById('userChoice').value;

                if (userChoice === "rock" || userChoice === "Rock") {
                    userChoice = "rock";
                    //document.getElementById("userPic").src = "rock.jpg";

                } else if (userChoice === "paper" || userChoice === "Paper") {
                    userChoice = "paper";
                   // document.getElementById("userPic").src = "paper.jpg";

                } else if (userChoice === "scissors" || userChoice === "Scissors") {
                    userChoice = "scissors";
                   // document.getElementById("userPic").src = "scissors.jpg";
                };



                if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
                    referee = "Tie!";
                }else if (userChoice === 'rock') {
                    if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
                        referee = 'Computer Wins!';
                        computerScore = ++computerScore;    
                    } else if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
                        referee = 'You Wins!';
                        userScore = ++userScore;
                    };
                }else if (userChoice === 'paper') {
                    if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
                        referee = 'Computer Wins!';
                        computerScore = ++computerScore;    
                    } else if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
                        referee = 'You Wins!';
                        userScore = ++userScore;
                    };
                }else if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
                    if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
                        referee = 'Computer Wins!';
                        computerScore = ++computerScore;    
                    } else if (computerChoice === 'paper') {
                        referee = 'You Wins!';
                        userScore = ++userScore;
                    };
                };
    document.getElementById('ref').value = referee;
    document.getElementById('userScore').value = userScore;
    document.getElementById('compScore').value =computerScore;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form>

        <div class="box"><img id="userPic" src="rps.jpg"></div>
        <div class="box"><img id="compPic" src="rps.jpg"></div>
        <br class="clear"><br>

        <div class="wrap">
            <label for="userScore">User Score:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="userScore" id="userScore" value="" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <label for="ref">Referee:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="ref" id="ref" placeholder="Referee's Call..." value="" readonly>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <label for="compScore">Computer Score:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="compScore" id="compScore" value="" readonly>
        </div>

        <br class="clear"><br>

        <label for="userChoice">Choose Your Weapon:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="userChoice" id="userChoice" placeholder="Rock, Paper, or Scissors?">
        <input type="button" value="Battle!" onclick="startGame()">

    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good Call on the score variables. I have moved them outside of the function. The user score variable is set to the user score input field but it still isn't working...

Comment: Kindly update the changes you had made in the code in question too

Comment: Create the variables and then set them to the input values at the end of the script! Vineet Thank you! I had a suspicion that i needed to do something like this but I couldn't wrap my head around it.